# Python logger duplicate logs

Tags: python, logging

I am using a class to create logs for a program I am developing. in the log files I am getting duplicate lines. My code is as follows:

```
import logging

class Log():
    def __init__(self,name=''):
    self.name='name'

def InitLog(self,name):
  self.logger = logging.getLogger(name)
  self.hdlr = logging.FileHandler('/'+name+'.log')
  self.formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
  self.hdlr.setFormatter(self.formatter)
  self.logger.addHandler(self.hdlr) 
  self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def E(self,msg):
  self.logger.error(msg)

def I(self,msg):
  self.logger.info(msg)
```

Calling the logger:

```
# Setup Log
log_url_thread_worker=Log()
log_url_thread_worker.InitLog(cyberlocker)
# Logging something
log_url_thread_worker.I(error)
```

can anyone see if im doing something stupid?

thanks

Comment: How are calling the logger for logging? Post that code too.

Comment: Are you sure you are not calling log from multiple threads?

Comment: Yes I am creating an instance in each process... Maybe that is the problem!

Comment: Yes that's the problem you are appending more and more handles to the logger

Comment: Ah yeah my bad, I thought because each process was separate it would need it's own instance of Log. Thanks!